# Sending data trough serial port only works when using a socat passthrough but not by writing to port directly

Tags: linux, rust, command-line, arduino

I am trying to write a rust program that send data to an Arduino through USB serial.

Arduino is on Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0.

For debugging, I need to sniff what is sent to the Arduino by using this command :

```
socat -x -v /dev/ttyUSB0,rawer,b115200,crnl PTY,link=/tmp/ttyV1,rawer,crnl
```

I then write the data from the rust code to the /tmp/ttyV1 port, and can read what is sent with the command.

When I do this, everything works fine, Arduino receives the data and behaves as expected.

However, if I do not run the command and write from the rust code directly to the /dev/ttyUSB0, the Arduino does not receive the data.

Rust code:

```
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::fs::read_to_string;


fn write_to_serial(jsondata: &[u8], port: &mut serialport::TTYPort) {


    match port.write(jsondata) {
        Ok(_) => {
            std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        }
        Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::TimedOut => (),
        Err(e) => eprintln!("{:?}", e),
    }
}

fn main() {
    //let serial_port = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
    let serial_port = "/tmp/ttyV1";
    let baud_rate = 115_200;

    let mut port = serialport::new(serial_port, baud_rate)
        .open_native()
        .expect("Failed to open port");

    let jsondata = read_to_string("src/greenwall.json").unwrap();
    write_to_serial(jsondata.as_bytes(), &mut port);
}
```

Line 18 is commented when using the socat command, line 19 is commented while not using the socat command (and line 18 uncommented).

I know there is no issue with the Arduino code and the rust code as it is working as expected when using /tmp/ttyV1. I guess there is some kind of formatting happening with the socat command, but does not manage to understand what.

Of course I cannot know what is happening on the port when not working, it's like a quantic bug that appears only when I cannot see what is happening on the port.

Thanks

EDIT: Not using rust at all, `cat src/greenwall.json > /dev/ttyUSB0` only works if I launched a `tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0` command prior.

EDIT2: [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/17efgos/writing_to_devttyusb0_only_works_when_i_have_a/) that solved my issue

Comment: I don't know `serialport`, but I notice that neither your code nor the `impl Drop`of `TTYPort` flushes the underlying `fd`. It is possible that `ttyV1` is unbuffered while `ttyUSB0` is not, which would mean that your implicitly rely on `socat` flushing (and therefor actually writing) the data.

Comment: I wonder if `serialport` is even necessary here or if you can just open it as a file for writing.

Comment: Yes, so not using my rust code, and just doing `cat src/greenwall.json > /tmp/ttyV1` works fine with the socat command, but `cat src/greenwall.json > /dev/ttyUSB0` does not. I'll investigate if this is a flushing issue. Thanks.

Comment: What is really weird is that if I execute `tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0` in a terminal, `cat src/greenwall.json > /dev/ttyUSB0` is working fine and send data to the arduino...